# Why don't I get an error message for failing to initializing an inherited classes instance attribute in an instance of it's derived class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

When I initialize an instance of class B, shouldn't it raise an error for not attempting to supply a value for the x attribute in class A's **init** method? What if I want an error to be raised if x is not supplied a value?

Example:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class B(A):

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

z = B(4) #Shouldn't I be getting an error for not attempting to 
         #initialize x from the base class?
```

Comment: I think you mean instance "attribute", not "property" which has a different meaning in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
What you are doing is initializing y, since in your **init** of B class, you are not calling your parents constructror

```
super.__init__()
```

If you wanted to use both x,y from B and having to initialize x from B, you should use this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class B(A):  
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x)
        self.y = y
```

Comment: But if I fail to initialize x from the B class why does it not throw an error? Maybe I'm misunderstanding how inheritance works in Python.

Comment: Since you are not using super.__init__(), you are not initializing your parents (class A) constructor, therefor not using x.
You just inherit it, without inheriting the parent constructor.  Just the parent methods (which are 0 in the example)

If you used your parents super() and didn't provide 2 values, an error would be raised.

Comment: Thanks makes sense.